# Where should the .vimrc file be located on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vimrc

I recently installed vim on Windows 7 as a stand-alone binary.

Where should I put my .vimrc file?

Comment: But is it not true that on Windows it is a `_vimrc` file?

Comment: Windows gvim (either Cygwin or Native) will opt for _gvimrc, .gvimrc, _vimrc and finally _vimrc in that order of priority.  It unders the underscore and dot format for the vimrc.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file

Answer (score 231, accepted):

From the [Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file).

> In Vim, your home directory is specified with $HOME. On Unix systems, this is your ~ directory. On Windows systems, the best way to find the value of $HOME is from within Vim, as follows. These commands are useful to see what directories your Vim is using:

```
:version
:echo expand('~')
:echo $HOME
:echo $VIM
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
```

Once you determine the `HOME` variable put the `vimrc` file within that directory.

If you would like to change your `HOME` variable, set `HOME` as an environment variable for either the system or user.

Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables > User | System Variables.

Windows (both Native and Cygwin*) will use `_gvimrc`, `.gvimrc`, `_vimrc` and `.vimrc` in that order of priority.  The gvim* files will be checked with the gvim process, while the console vim will only check the vim* files.

*: verified against vim 7.2 and 7.3

Comment: (For those like me, who only use Windows when forced to): remember to enable showing file extensions. "_gvimrc.txt" etc. doesn't work. ;)

Comment: To have `HOME` match the behavior of Unix systems, I'd create a global environmental variable of `%USERPROFILE%` if that's not already done.

Comment: It is good to look in each directory listed in the answer because my `_vimrc` is in `$ VIM`. Although, the `_vimrc` is read only file.

Comment: Setting HOME in the user environment variables did the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 28):

For Vim 7.4, these are the paths it looks for on Windows

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc"
3rd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
```

As [Darren Hall](https://superuser.com/users/16039/darren-hall) said, use these commands to find out the values of `$VIM` and `$HOME`.

```
:echo $HOME
:echo $VIM
```

For example, one good place for gvim-specific settings would be

```
C:\Users\MyUsername\_gvimrc
```

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way I found is to simply echo the location of the vimrc file currently in use - you can then replace with your own custom version.

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to find out just from a .bat file first look in the `%HOME%` directory. If that is not defined then vim/gvim looks in the path defined by concatenating `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATH%`.

Answer (score 1):

That is actually a good question because after installation (oddly enough) you get a _vimrc file under "Program Files" - which is not a good place for configuration files.

Put it under

```
%USERPROFILE%\vimfiles\_vimrc
```

This way it will be picked up instead of the configuration file put by the installation.

Comment: When I run `:version` from VIM, the two options that appear (most similar to what your answer is) are: `"$HOME\_vimrc"` and `"$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"`, but not `_vimrc` within the `vimfiles` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found that vim-tux installed via Chocolatey can see .vimrc files only under C:\Users\MyUsername\vimfiles though :version tells that C:\Users\MyUsername also included.

Answer (score 0):

I find that when I open gvim from Windows file explorer, **$HOME** is set to c:\Users\*myname* but when launched from my Cygwin file explorer it is set to /cygwin/home/*myname*.  This is good because it lets me put slightly different settings in each one.  To keep things separate and make backup easier, the Windows one is called **_vimrc** and the Cygwin one is called **.vimrc**.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in ( windows 10 )

```
\tools\vim\_vimrc
```