# gVim control characters on Windows

Tags: vim, gvim, control-characters

I copied some data from an app and it has lots of `^D`s and `^M`s in it. I got rid of `^D` with no problem using `:%s/^D//g` and I know I can remove `^M` with something like `:%s/^V^M//g` but the problem is that I'm running on windows and `^V` is Ctrl-V, which pastes data from the clipboard into gvim. How do I escape the paste function of `^V`/ctrl-V in Windows for vim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from `:help CTRL-V-alternative`:

```
                                                *CTRL-V-alternative* *CTRL-Q*
Since CTRL-V is used to paste, you can't use it to start a blockwise Visual
selection.  You can use CTRL-Q instead.  You can also use CTRL-Q in Insert
mode and Command-line mode to get the old meaning of CTRL-V.  But CTRL-Q
doesn't work for terminals when it's used for control flow.
```

Answer (score 5):

Another Way, specific for ^M, would be to use `:%s/\r//g` since ^M is a carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

To use your familiar MS Windows hotkeys for copy, paste etc. use the mswin.vim file as your configuration.  Copy it from your install path to where your $HOME directory is, renamed to _vimrc.  Type :echo $HOME to figure out where that is.  Usually something like C:\Users\'username'. Restart gVim and your regular Windows Ctrl-V, Ctrl-C type of hotkeys should work.

See [Where should the .vimrc file be located on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/86246/where-should-vimrc-file-be-located-on-windows-7) for a little more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `:%s/\r/**\r\l**/g`. This will convert your carriage return to Windows style carriage return + line feed combination.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with vi inside conemu and other programs which interrupt keystrokes and replace them with other actions.

I got around this by using ^K (Ctrl-K) to enter a digraph for the search and replace.

For example I wanted to remove NUL (0x00) characters and CR (^M or 0xd) characters

Normally I would Use ^V000 and ^V^M however with the default digraphs defined you can use the following (note ^K is pressing Ctrl and K)

```
:%s/[^KNU^KCR]//g
```

If those digraphs are not working you can see the currently set ones with

```
:dig
```

To see how to define your own see

```
:help :dig
```