# how to set environment variables in VM Fusion Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, environment-variables, vmware-fusion, r

I have installed windows 7 just fine via VM Fusion, but am having trouble setting environment variables, as i cannot edit files on the `C:` drive.

A specific example is the trouble i'm having with `R` (i am also having trouble setting up `gvim`). I think both are related, so i'll just show the `R` problem.

The problem with R is that i cannot install packages, as i do not have permission.

```
Warning in install.packages("xts") :
'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("xts") : 
unable to create ‘\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents/R/winlibrary/3.2’
In addition: Warning message: 
In dir.create(userdir, recursive = TRUE) : 
cannot create dir '\\vmware-host\Shared Folders', reason 'Invalid argument'
```

I have hacked around this by setting the `.libPaths` variable manually (`.libPaths("Z:/Documents/Winz/Rstuff/pax/")`), however the packages do not survive a re-boot of the VM Windows emulator.

In any case, as i cannot get R to pick up the `.Rprofile` file, no matter where i place it (nor will it pick up the edits i've made to `Rprofile.site`).

I am sure it's must be something about permissions, as i also cannot get `gvim` to pick up my `.vimrc` ... but i cannot figure it out.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Since you installed Win 7 you must have admin privs. Just change the permissions on `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/library`. For `gvim` : http://superuser.com/questions/86246/where-should-the-vimrc-file-be-located-on-windows-7. I guess a bigger question is do you _need_ your home directory to be a shared folder? You can just share a `data` and `output` folder for things to be accessible from both guest & host.

Comment: @hrbrmstr do i change the permissions in windows or OSX? And how do i do so? Thanks